# creating simple calculator using recursive function in C programming

Tags: c, recursion

OK I read the comment and tried to improve the code by adding if statement for stopping the recursion, but I am still getting this error:

0xC00000FD: Stack overflow(parameter: 0x00000001, 0x00322FB0).
(I am using Korean version of the complier so I translated the error message)

I am trying to make a simple calculator that has 3 functions using recursion

The number     + or -  function(number, operation)

I have two functions for receiving an operator and number

and one recursive function for doing the recursion.

Here is what I did but I am keep getting errors. Could you share some of your wisdom to me?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

//Input: 'sub_exp' the value of the sub expression to the left of'op'
//op: an operator: + or -
//Effect: the whole expression is evaluated using recursion
//output: this ufnctino returns the value of the expression
float s_exp(float sub_exp, char op)
{

    switch (op)
    {
    case '+':
    return sub_exp + s_exp(sub_exp, op) ;   //add the function recursively
    break;
    case '-':
    return sub_exp- s_exp(sub_exp,op); //subtract the function recursively
    break;

    }


}

float get_num() //this function receives number
{
    static float num;
    printf("please input the numerical value \n");
    scanf_s("%f", &num);
    printf("%5.5f", num);

    return num;
}
char get_op() //this function receives an operator
{
    static char oper;
    //receives the variables and returns the variable 
    printf("please input the operator");
    scanf_s("%c",&oper);
    printf("\n %c", oper);

    return oper;

}

void main(void){
    //run the recursive function
    s_exp(get_num(), get_op());



}
```

Comment: what are your errors ?

Comment: `s_exp` needs a way to end the recursion: the "base case". This is the condition under which recursion should stop and the function should return. Currently there is no base case, so the function will continue until the stack overflows (kind of like an infinite loop).

Comment: Please be more specific with what you mean by "keep getting errors". Having said that, as is I don't see how your recursion ever terminates.

Comment: `scanf_s("%c",&oper);` maybe should be `scanf_s(" %c",1, &oper);`